# Trying to retrieve place details but getting error. Google places api

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps-api-3, google-api-java-client, openrefine

Ive been trying to extract Google place details using a place id column but it keeps throwing an error if i try to reference the placeid column. However, when i put in the placeid column manually it works perfectly. Can someone highlight whats wrong with my code.

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=["colummn"].value&key=************"

Comment: It's nearly impossible to tell you exactly what's wrong with your code without looking at your code.

Comment: If it works when you manually enter the number, it's likely the string expansion  from ["column"].value isn't working. 

Please add more of your existing code and it would be easier to tell.

Comment: Hi, im using openrefine.  I am trying to fetch column details using a URL. I have the placeid already but i need to use the placeid column to get place details using google place api.   the url im trying to use to get the same is above.

Comment: Hi, how can i extract some field from the place details i got ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenRefine, the right syntax is :

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" 

+ 

cells['column name'].value 

+ "&key=YOURKEY"
```

Comment: Hi, how can i extract some field of the place details i got ?